How to connect Flutter app to local Node.js backend with MongoDB?
I'm trying to connect my Flutter app to a local Node.js backend that uses MongoDB as the database. The backend connects successfully to the MongoDB database running on localhost, as evidenced by the “Database connected” message in the terminal output. However, when trying to access the backend API from the Flutter app using the URL http://10.0.2.2:8082, I get a “Connection refused” error in the emulator.
Here's the relevant code:
Node.js Backend:
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { MONGO_DB_CONFIG } = require("./config/app.config");
const errors = require("./middleware/errors");

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(MONGO_DB_CONFIG.DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(
    () => {
        console.log("Database connected")
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log("Database can't be connected: " + error);
    }
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/app.routes"));
app.use(errors.errorHandler);

app.listen(process.env.port || 4000, function () {
    console.log("Ready to go !");
})


Flutter App:
class Config {
  static const String appName = "Shopping App";
  static const String apiURL = "http://10.0.2.2:8082";
  static const String productURL = "/api/products";
}

I've tried different URLs in the Flutter app, such as localhost:4000 and 127.0.0.1:4000, but the issue persists.
I've also tried running the backend on different ports, but the problem remains the same.
I've verified that the backend is running and can be accessed from Postman using http://localhost:4000/api/products/.
Could you please help me understand what I'm missing and how to properly configure the Flutter app to connect to the local Node.js backend?

In the emulator, if you turn off WiFi and use mobile data does it work?

Hello, don't work

In your FE flutter code you have if(model.hasData) { return productList(model.data); } return const Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
which may be why you're only seeing your spinning progress circle, since if the database has no data and null is returned this logic will never be true.
It could also be that you need to use setState to update the value in model and notify the framework.

When you run it on real device does it work? or not?

Does the future fail model.hasError and if what is model.error?
